# Delete all data outside square brackets

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I delete all data outside square brackets `[]`?

Example: from

```
[lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1] lipsum2;[lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1] lipsum2
```

I want to obtain:

```
[lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1] [lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1]
```

Comment: FYI, those are square brackets, not parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[` and `]` as the field separators, and print every 2nd field:

```
awk -F '[][]' '{for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) printf "[%s]%s", $i, OFS; print ""}' <<END
[lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1] lipsum2;[lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1] lipsum2
a [b] c [d] e
nothing here
[one thing]
END
```

```
[lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1] [lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1] 
[b] [d] 

[one thing]
```

This weird looking field separator `[][]` is a regular expression that matches either the `[` character or the `]` character. When given your sample input, awk will break down the fields like this:

1. "" (empty string)
2. "lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1"
3. " lipsum2;" (with a leading space)
4. "lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1"
5. " lipsum2" (with a leading space)

So you can see that you want to output fields #2 and #4 (adding the brackets back) with a space in between.
The `for` loop iterates over fields 2, 4, 6, and so on.
The `printf` command formats the output as desired -- the default OFS (output field separator) is a space.
The `print ""` line just adds the newline after the loop is done.

Comment: This will add a space at the end of each line, except blank lines.

Comment: No way! Trade secret! ;) I'll add some notes to my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -e 's/^[^\[]*//;s/\][^\[]*\[/\] \[/g;s/[^]]*$//;' <<'EOF'
lipsum0 [lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1] lipsum2;[lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1] lipsum2
EOF
[lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1] [lipsum1;limpsum1;lipsum1]
```

How this works:

1. Remove everything up to the first `[`: `s/^[^\[]*//`
2. Replace everything between `]` and `[` with a space: `s/\][^\[]*\[/\] \[/`
3. Remove everything after the last `]`: `s/[^]]*$//`

This of course only works if the brackets are normalised.

Comment: @ I0b0, it works smoothly, thanks, but curiosity... what do you mean with normalized?

Comment: That there are no unmatched, single `[` or `]` characters.