# How to delete everything outside of {} braces in BASH?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to delete all data appearing outside of `{` and `}` brackets. E.g., here is the line `$variable`:

```
The fish {{went}} to the {{restaurant}} to eat some {fish} for lunch.
```

The output, after deleting everything outside the paired `{`'s and `}`'s would just be:

```
{{went}}{{restaurant}}{fish}
```

- All braces appear in pairs.

I've found the post [Delete all data outside square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298138/delete-all-data-outside-square-brackets), which is similar, and deals with square braces, but my attempt to modify the two answers to work failed, because both `[` and `{` can have multiple meanings within the code, either as the symbol displayed in the original data, or as something `sed` or `awk` or regular expressions use. This is what I tried, based on the answers in the other post.

```
awk -F '\{\}\{\}' '{for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) printf "[%s]%s", $i, OFS; print ""}' <<< "$variable"

sed -e 's/^[^\{]*//;s/\}[^\{]*\[/\} \[/g;s/[^{]*$//;' <<< "$variable"
```

How can I make the proper modifications so that one of these will delete all data outside of the braces?

Comment: Will the brackets ever be nested? i.e.  The {{quick brown {{fox}} jumped}} over the lazy dog.

Comment: No, they are never nested as you show.

Comment: Another example: `deleted {{not deleted}} deleted {not deleted}{{not deleted}} deleted`.

Comment: Just making sure since that would be a harder problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ echo "The fish {{went}} to the {{restaurant}} to eat some {fish} for lunch." |
sed -r 's/(^|\})[^{}]+(\{|$)/\1\2/g'
{{went}}{{restaurant}}{fish}
```

or with GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ echo "The fish {{went}} to the {{restaurant}} to eat some {fish} for lunch." |
gawk -v FPAT='{[^}]+}+' -v OFS= '{$1=$1}1'
{{went}}{{restaurant}}{fish}
```

Comment: Well done. It works equally well for `'The fish {{went}} to the {{restaurant}} to eat some {fish} and {chips} and {{drink}} lots of {whiskey} for lunch.'` yielding: `{{went}}{{restaurant}}{fish}{chips}{{drink}}{whiskey}`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using grep. The -P means to use Perl syntax which allows for non-greedy expressions and the -o prints only the match.

```
echo "The fish {{went}} to the {{restaurant}} to eat some {fish} for lunch." |
grep -Po '{?{[^{}]+}}?'
```

Comment: To put it all on one line, pipe into `| paste -sd ''`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^{]*\(\({{*[^}]*}}*\)*\)/\1/g' file
```

or:

```
sed -r 's/[^{]*((\{+[^}]*\}+)*)/\1/g' file
```

Assuming all `{` and `}`  are balanced.

N.B. This avoids alternation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using vanilla `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^{]*\|[^}]*$//g; s/}[^{}]*{/}{/g' <<< "$variable"
```

Results:

```
{{went}}{{restaurant}}{fish}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party. Here is a `perl` solution.

```
perl -ne'print for /{[^}]+}+/g'
```

or if you prefer a new line at the end then

```
perl -ne'print for /{[^}]+}+/g }{ print "\n"'
```

```
$ echo "The fish {{went}} to the {{restaurant}} to eat some {fish} for lunch." | 
perl -ne'print for /{[^}]+}+/g }{ print "\n"'
{{went}}{{restaurant}}{fish}
```